# A simple circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, memristor

[image]

This image shows a circuit with 7 memristors and an amplifier. It would be some help if anyone could tell if it is possible to understand (only using the picture) what kind of a circuit this is. I tried as an op-amp adder but it didn't work. I need to find Vout.

Comment: Are you sure those are all resistors, Dave? They look like memristors to me...

Comment: Indeed they are memristors.

Comment: Right - I don't know much about memristors at all (so I would be interested in the answer to this question)

Comment: It's really impossible to say without knowing more about the nature of the amplifier. Should we assume that it has high input impedance, or should we assume that its input is a "virtual ground"? Either configuration is possible -- and commonly used -- but the answer to your question will depend very strongly on which it is.

Comment: Virtual ground must work.